# comparing two strings in swift with less code

Tags: ios, swift

I have one array for two different cities to choose from
the goal is to compare these two cities and the result will be the distance between them
I achieved that, but the problem is it takes so many lines of code
I think it's possible to be less than that,

what I did so far :

the result distince is define as below :

```
   let from_A_to_b =   423
    let from_A_to_c =   1439
    let from_A_to_d =   1122
   ...
```

and i have one array prisnted in tableview to choose from and pass the data:

```
var city = ["A","B","C","D"]
```

the compare code is :

```
 if (passedCity.text  == "A") && (passedCity2.text  == "B") {
                result.text =  "\(from_A_to_b) km "
  } else if (passedCity.text  == "A") && (passedCity2.text  == "C") {
                result.text = "\(from_A_to_c) km "
  } else if (passedCity.text  == "A") && (passedCity2.text  == "D") {
                result.text = "\(from_A_to_d) km "
  }
```

in this case, I will repeat the code multiple times,
I think I could make this work with a for-in loop
but I don't know how
sorry for this beginner Q

Comment: You can use a `switch` on a tuple composed of `passedCity.text` & `passedCity2.text`: `switch (passedCity.text, passedCity2.text) { case ("A", "B": result.text = "\(from_A_to_b) km", case (...)... }`?

Comment: @Larme using tuple! interesting approach.

Comment: You should probably use `MKDistanceFormatter` or `MeasurementFormatter`.

Comment: Also, you could store the distances in a dictionary `[(String, String): Int]`, meaning `[(city1, city2): distance]`.

Comment: @Sulthan Can you put tuples as dictionary keys though? Pretty sure they are not hashable.

Comment: @Sweeper I am pretty sure they already are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your data table is hardcoded where each data has its worn property there is no non-hacky way to accomplish this with less code then one line per entry.

(A "hacky" way would be to generate a string representing a name of property and constructing a selector from string to access property directly, unsafely...)

In any of cases I would first create an enumeration with your cities

```
enum City: CaseIterable {
    case cityA
    case cityB
    case cityC
    case cityD
}
```

then use some display name such as

```
extension City {
    
    var displayName: String {
        switch self {
        case .cityA: return "City A"
        case .cityB: return "City B"
        case .cityC: return "City C"
        case .cityD: return "City D"
        }
    }
    
}
```

I would try to have 2 properties in your code as

```
var selectedCityFrom: City
var selectedCityTo: City
```

and use those directly instead of converting them to-from strings. But if you insist on strings you can now do:

```
extension City {

    static func fromName(_ displayName: String) -> City? {
        self.allCases.first(where: { $0.displayName == displayName })
    }
```

Doing this you now solve getting a concrete object from your strings and you can do:

```
guard let fromText = passedCity.text, let fromCity = City.fromName(fromText) else { return }
guard let toText = passedCity2.text, let toCity = City.fromName(toText) else { return }

let distance = City.getDistanceBetween(fromCity, toCity)
print(distance)
```

And now on the other side it is probably easiest to just have an array of your data such as `[(from: City, to: City, distance: Double)]`:

```
extension City {

    private static let distances: [(from: City, to: City, distance: Double)] = [
        (.cityA, .cityB, 423),
        (.cityA, .cityC, 1439),
        (.cityA, .cityD, 1122)
    ]
    
    static func getDistanceBetween(_ from: City, _ to: City) -> Double? {
        guard from != to else { return 0.0 } // It is a same city
        guard let match = City.distances.first(where: { ($0.from == from && $0.to == to) || ($0.to == from && $0.from == to) }) else { return nil } // Data for this combination is missing
        return match.distance
    }

}
```

Probably it makes more sense that you actually move this table to some external JSON which can be bundled with application or even sent via some API from remote server. In that case it is more likely you will rather generate keys like `cityA_cityB` and have a table `[String: Double]`. For instance:

```
{
    "cityA_cityB": 423,
    "cityA_cityC": 1439,
    "cityA_cityD": 1122
}
```

then you would need to build something like this:

```
extension City {

    var JSONKey: String {
        switch self {
        case .cityA: return "cityA"
        case .cityB: return "cityB"
        case .cityC: return "cityC"
        case .cityD: return "cityD"
        }
    }
    
    static func getDistanceBetween(_ from: City, _ to: City, fromJSON jsonData: [String: Double]) -> Double? {
        guard from != to else { return 0.0 } // It is a same city
        
        let normalKey = [from.JSONKey, to.JSONKey].joined(separator: "_")
        let reversedKey = [to.JSONKey, from.JSONKey].joined(separator: "_")
        
        return jsonData[normalKey] ?? jsonData[reversedKey]
    }
```

But there are very many ways to accomplish this same result. I hope this helps you finding the one that suits you best.

Comment: clever!, just what i'm lovking for , thank you my friend